# unable to install git on ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, git

I am trying to install git on Ubuntu 16.04 with `sudo apt-get install git`:

```
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

if you have any idea please help

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg install -f`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

If that doesn't resolve your issue check if you can install it from the **Ubuntu software center**.

If still facing issues head over to the [github page](https://github.com/git/git), download zip and install.